# Can part of a file name be used as a hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, filenames, hyperlink

I have created a word document using Word 2010. The file name is broken into 2 parts, I have the start which is an alphanumeric code (that changes every time I make a change to the document by me), the second part is the actual name of the file. For example, I could have a file name as "IE-00244-A Writing this blog". If I make a change, I resave it as IE-00244-B Writing this blog".

I have this file location linked through my website but I don't want to have to relink it every time I make a change. What I want to do is link to the second part of the file name i.e. "Writing this blog" so I only link once to it and every time I update the file and change the full file name, I am still linking to the part of the file name called "Writing this blog". Once I remove the older version and am left with the updated version, I want this link from my website to see it as essentially the same file.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you must use a full file name in a hyperlink on a website, otherwise the link will not work. What you are wanting to do has more to do with coding of the web page related to how to handle hyperlinks.

**A possible solution** - I am assuming you are saving the Word document locally, then uploading it to your site. If this is the case, name the file on the server `Writing this blog.docx`. When you upload your recent version simply rename it to the same name and overwrite the file on the server. This will leave your link intact, while at the same time you've retained your file naming scheme.

Comment: Thanks but the file name needs to be something like "ABD-12345-A Writing this blog.doc" and every time i update the file, it becomes "ABD-12345-B Writing this blog.doc", "ABD-12345-C Writing this blog.doc" etc.. so when i hyperlink the document initially, it will work fine but because the updated and subsequent versions will be different (just an increment of a letter), it will no longer be recognised as the same file. It is a project and i needs this naming convention so i'm looking to only link the "Writing this blog"

Comment: part and then any updates i do will still hold the correct naming convention but from an access point of view from the website, it will always pull the correct file as the most recent updated one will still have those words in it's file name.

Comment: I understood your question.